# Purpose of (fn...)() brackets in Self-Executing Anonymous Functions? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)

Question is a duplicate of 
[Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)
and 
[What do parentheses surrounding a object/function/class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-me)

Just curious really, what are the purposes of the brackets in this code:

```
(function() {})();
```

This looks like I could just as easily write:

```
var x=function(){};
(x)();
```

With jQuery plugins we would do something like...

```
(function($) {})(jQuery);
```

What's the deal with the brackets?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions) and of [Is there a difference between (function() {…}()); and (function() {…})(); ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783007/is-there-a-difference-between-function-and-function)

Comment: @Gumbo: yes, found [a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-object-function-class-declaration-me) (already a duplicate as well).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Please close this. In Canada we don't commonly use the term parenthesis to refer to any of these charecters: () {} [], which get called brackets (eg, we call it BEDMAS instead of PEDMAS)

Comment: @user257493 - [ **Wikipedia expounds on brackets.** ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the parentheses (surrounding the function), you don't have to declare a name, littering the namespace.  And, they serve to alert readers of your code to the fact that you're using a self-invoking function.

The second set of parentheses actually invoke/call the (anonymous) function you just created.  Since Javascript functions are actually just variables (or "first-class objects" in CS-speak), you've just created a variable (in the first set of parentheses), which you call using the second set.

Here's an example:

```
function callFunc(f) {
    return f("test");
}

callFunc(alert);
```

In the example, `f` actually references the function `alert`, which you call in the function code with the parentheses.

Comment: Why do I almost always see a set of brackets right after the part that encapsulates the function? Did you happen to know the ecma section that describes this behavior?

Comment: @user257493: those parentheses actually invoke the function.

Comment: as a note: one parenthesis, two parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

In case of the jQuery example you define an anonymous function that takes a parameter called $ and then pass the jQuery object to it. It will stay inside that scope and not conflict with other frameworks that have $ globally defined.

Other than that, personally it looks cleaner to me.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with what the jQuery plugin code does as much as I am the purposes of the brackets.

Comment: That's more the reason for enclosing the code in a function, and not so much a reason for the parentheses themselves.