# How does parser parse the following expression: new init()?

Tags: javascript, function, parsing, new-operator, invoke

Given the following:

```
 function init() { return 1; }
```

how does parser parse

```
 new init();
```

?

I mean why `init()` function works together with `new` operator? Why function was not invoked independently?

Comment: you must do some basic research first start from here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4212149/init-function-in-javascript-and-how-it-works)

Comment: @AsteriskNinja: I don't see what that post has to do with the question.

Answer (score 0):

> Why function was not invoked independently?

Simply because that's the rule. `new`, `init` and the argument parentheses are four separate tokens, which together will form a constructor call. If `new` is not there, three tokens will form a normal function call.

To get it invoked independently, you could write `new (init())` or `new (init())()` (not working of course as `init()` does not return a constructor).