# Are "(function ( ) { } ) ( )" and "(function ( ) { } ( ) )" functionally equal in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function

Both of these code blocks below alert `foo` then `bar`. The only difference is `})()` and `}())`.

Code 1:

```
(function()
{
    bar = 'bar';
    alert('foo');
})();

alert(bar);
```

Code 2:

```
(function()
{
    bar = 'bar';
    alert('foo');
}());

alert(bar);
```

So is there any difference, apart from the syntax?

Comment: See also [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions) or [Is there a difference between (function() {…}()); and (function() {…})();?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783007/is-there-a-difference-between-function-and-function)

Comment: just when u think everything in JS is not what u expect - it is. tricked again! js first language to use reverse pschology!!!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No; they are identical

---

However, if you add `new` beforehand and `.something` afterwards, they will be different.

## Code 1

```
new (function() {
    this.prop = 4;
}) ().prop;
```

This code creates a new instance of this function's class, then gets the `prop` property of the new instance.
It returns `4`.

It's equivalent to

```
function MyClass() {
    this.prop = 4;
}
new MyClass().prop;
```

---

## Code 2

```
new ( function() {
    return { Class: function() { } }; 
}() ).Class;
```

This code calls `new` on the `Class` property.
Since the parentheses for the function call are inside the outer set of parentheses, they aren't picked up by the `new` expression, and instead call the function normally, returning its return value.
The `new` expression parses up to the `.Class` and instantiates that.  (the parentheses after `new` are optional)

It's equivalent to

```
var namespace = { Class: function() { } };

function getNamespace() { return namespace; }

new ( getNamespace() ).Class;
//Or,
new namespace.Class;
```

Without the parentheses around the call to `getNamespace()`, this would be parsed as `(new getNamespace()).Class` — it would call instantiate the `getNamespace` class and return the `Class` property of the new instance.

Comment: The `new...prop` examples are helpful. Thanks.

Comment: There's also a difference whenever it's directly preceded by an identifier, which might happen by accident if you don't use semicolons in your JavaScript. `a(function () { return 5; }())` reduces to `a(5)` whereas `a(function () { return 5; })()` reduces to `a()()` which further reduces to `5()`, which is illegal.

Comment: Effectively the parenthesis act as a temporary anonymous variable on "Code 2".

You could also write `var f = function(){ ... }();`

It would output the same result.

Answer (score 7):

There's no difference - the opening brace only serves as a syntactic hint to tell the parser that what follows is a *function expression* instead of a *function declaration*.

Answer (score 6):

There's no difference. Both are function expressions.

There is be a third way, too:

```
+function() {
    bar = 'bar';
    alert('foo');
}();
```

(instead of the `+` another operator would work, too)

The most common way is

```
(function() {
    // ...
})();
```

though.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/self-invoking-function

Comment: The name "self-invoking function" is misleading, since the function doesn't invoke itself in its body recursively, but it is *being* invoked immediately after definition. I'd rather call it "immediately invoked function".