# how would you pass in parameters to a constructor when written like new(Date)?

Tags: javascript, constructor

As a corollary to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236058/what-is-the-difference-between-newdate-and-new-date) question, if you created an object in javascript using the syntax `new (Date)` how would you pass in any constructor args/params?

In other words is there an equivalent of `new Date(2000)` or is that just how you would do it?

Comment: Although you _can_ do this (as per the answers already posted), I don't understand why you would want to. Even without parameters, the parentheses around `(Date)` are redundant, so why include them?

Comment: yeah. my sentiments exactly. but i just had to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parens return the result of the contained expression, so this will work:

```
new (Date)(2000);
```

This is the same as:

```
new Date(2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried: `new (Date)(2000)`? Not exactly pretty code...