# javascript anonymous function syntax variations

Tags: javascript, syntax, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)
>   [Are “(function ( ) { } ) ( )” and “(function ( ) { } ( ) )” functionally equal in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938802/are-function-and-function-functionally-equal-i)

I have seen the javascript anonymous functions written two different ways:

```
(function(){

})();
```

and

```
(function(){

}());
```

I have always thought the top one to be correct, and had never encountered the bottom one until now. I think this probably makes no difference at all but I thought I shoud be sure. Is there any difference between the two or are both ways equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're equivalent.

The opening parenthesis is the important bit - it's the one that helps the parser figure out that what's coming is a *function expression* rather than a *function declaration*.

See http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ for an explanation of the difference.

Comment: Did I just have a déjà vu or have you answered a same question with this same answer

Comment: @Esailija umm, if I did, I don't remember it...

Comment: lols, it's this one :D http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938802/are-function-and-function-functionally-equal-i/5938902#5938902 I remember cos I upvoted you for it. It even has the same italics.

Comment: @Esailija oh yeah :blush:  You have a good memory - that answer was a year ago today! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Oohh....... This was just for fun.....

---

<s>They are equal, but use this shorted closure way instead: (Twitter uses it!)</s>

```
!function(){

}();
```

You'll save many characters. 1 each time.

---

But I prefer to use this one that I think it's more readably:

```
(function(){

})();
```

than:

```
(function(){

}());
```

Comment: Not necessarily easier to understand though... in general, I think it's better to use code minifiers.

Comment: It is far more important for code to be obvious then it is for it to be short.

Comment: no, don't use that way - it's not as easily recognised.

Comment: Do NOT use `!function...` it seriously hurts readability. And it doesn't matter if Twitter uses it or not.

Comment: to be honest they all read the same to me, am I the only one who have developed a blind spot for this