# JavaScript Self Invoking Functions

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “(function ( ) { } ) ( )” and “(function ( ) { } ( ) )” functionally equal in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938802/are-function-and-function-functionally-equal-i)

Is there a difference between these two?

```
(function () {}());
```

and

```
(function () {})();
```

What do you think about this for building objects within a global:

```
;(function () {
            'use strict';

            this.menu = (function () {
                var version = "1.2.111",
                    someFunction = function() {
                        console.log("Version: " + version);
                        return version;
                    };
                return {
                    getVersion: someFunction
                };
            })();

            this.someObject = (function () {
                var privateVar = "1234",
                    privateFunction = function () {
                        console.log("Private Variable: " + privateVar);
                        return privateVar;
                    };

                return {
                    publicFunction: privateFunction
                };
            })();

        }).apply(window.saif = window.saif || {});
```

Comment: This is a really good question, I've been wondering the same thing for quite a while now... One thing I have noticed is that the variable scope changes between the two, I just can't precisely explain how they change... (I noticed I couldn't access some variables/functions within the (function(){})() method, in which I normally would in regular functions.

Comment: @sergiocruz: The variable scope will be the same for either syntax. If you noticed a change in the `this` value of a function, it wouldn't be because of a difference between the two examples at the top.