# how the functions parenthesis works?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between these two methods?

**method 1:**

```
(function(){
console.log('test');
}());
```

**method 2:**

```
(function(){
console.log('test');
})();
```

---

And why this doesn't work?

```
function(){
console.log('test');
}();
```

Comment: Show how you used it in your code; then only it can be justified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are "(function ( ) { } ) ( )" and "(function ( ) { } ( ) )" functionally equal in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938802/are-function-and-function-functionally-equal-i) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/difference-between-function-and-function and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14011509/javascript-self-invoking-functions and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647019/what-are-the-differences-between-these-three-types-of-module-pattern