# What's the difference between these three form of self-invoking anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, function, self-invoking-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “(function ( ) { } ) ( )” and “(function ( ) { } ( ) )” functionally equal in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938802/are-function-and-function-functionally-equal-i)

I'm reading the document below.

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#patternity

When I looked though these examples, self-invoking of an anonymous function had three forms.

The one was

```
(function() {
    //do something
})();
```

and another was

```
function() {
    //do something
}();
```

and the other was

```
(function() {
    //do something
}());
```

What's the difference between these three forms?

Thank you for your reading!

Comment: The second one is a syntax error if it stands alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first and last are effectively identical. The differences are a matter of style.

The second is unsafe as (depending on where it is) it could be a function *declaration* instead of a function *expression*, and you can't immediately invoke a function declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The proceeding function is not valid syntax:

```
function() {
    //do something
}();
```