# javascript call class from popup window

Tags: javascript, callback, popup, parent-child, parent

is there a way to callback a class object from popup window.

i know there is way to callback a function:

```
window.opener.MyFunction();
```

but i want to know, how to call class method

```
new Profile('me', 'id');
```

im not sure how to do it, but just to give you idea

```
window.opener.'new Profile('me', 'id');';
```

> yes i know, its not valid js code, but its just to give you idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Profile` is a property of `window.opener`.
You can use it like any other property:

```
new window.opener.Profile(...);
```

`new` is an operator that acts on a function; you can use it with any expression that returns a function.
You can even write

```
new (function() { ...}) (...);
```

For more pathological corner cases of this behavior, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5938845/34397).