# What effect does this syntax difference have (if any)?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a difference between (function() {…}()); and (function() {…})();?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783007/is-there-a-difference-between-function-and-function)

I have seen two slightly different ways of using the Self Executing Anonymous Function pattern.

1:

```
(function(){
    //do stuff
}())
```

2:

```
(function(){
    //do stuff
})();
```

Does the syntax difference have any implied effects that might not be obvious or are these two techniques exactly the same ?

Comment: ...my search term was *"javascript difference between function parentheses"* It was the fourth result, among many other commonly asked questions about such inline function invocations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same. People tend to rather use the first. I also think JSLint suggests the first version. I prefer the second. It's really up to you.

Comment: I do prefer the second too. I feel it more natural.

Comment: Absolutely. Curly braces directly followed by parenthesis are disgusting and scare me...:)

Answer (score 1):

that's absolute same

it called self-executed function

there are three pattern(but third pattern cannot return value)

one and two is your questions

one:

```
(function(){
    //do stuff
}())
```

two:

```
(function(){
    //do stuff
})();
```

and third is with '!' character

```
!function(){ 
    //do stuff
}();
```

good luck!

Comment: There are far more than three patterns. Nearly any operator can be used.

Comment: thx.. '-', '+' ...operator work too.