# who can help me optimized this javascript code?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

this is my part code,but a friend say the variable(like getStyle,getOffsetWidth,getOffsetHeight,log) will not release, so i want know why the variable will not release,and how to optimized it,thanks!

```
   var Util = (function() {
        "use strict";
        var getStyle = function(node) {
            var style = null;
            if (window.getComputedStyle) {
                style = window.getComputedStyle(node, null);
            } else {
                style = node.currentStyle;
            }
            return style;
        };

        var getOffsetWidth = function(style) {
            return parseInt(style.width, 10) +
                parseInt(style.paddingLeft, 10) +
                parseInt(style.paddingRight, 10) +
                parseInt(style.marginLeft, 10) +
                parseInt(style.marginRight, 10);
        };

        var getOffsetHeight = function(style) {
            return parseInt(style.height, 10) +
                parseInt(style.paddingTop, 10) +
                parseInt(style.paddingBottom, 10) +
                parseInt(style.marginTop, 10) +
                parseInt(style.marginBottom, 10);
        };

        var log = function() {
            if (window.console && window.console.log) {
                window.console.log(arguments);
            }
        };

        return {
            getStyle: getStyle,
            getOffsetWidth: getOffsetWidth,
            getOffsetHeight: getOffsetHeight,
            log: log
        };
    }());
```

Comment: What does _"variable does not release"_ mean, I don't understand...

Comment: You may want to change `}());` to `})();`. Aside from that, what does "does not release" mean? What variable was your friend referring to?

Comment: Have a look at the following page which explains javascript memory management and also talks about garbage collection : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: @Blender `}());` is also [valid syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3783287/621962).

Comment: @canon: Yep, which is why I said "may". It's the more common syntax, at least from the projects that I've looked at.

Comment: @Blender Douglas Crockford [uses `}());`](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html)... just fyi. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friend is probably referring to the fact that the variables `getStyle`, `getOffsetWidth`, etc are included in the closure of the returned methods. This is a tiny bit inefficient because those variables are never used again.

In a simple case like this, where the functions in your `Util` object are not making any use of the closure of the outer function, there's no reason not to just do:

```
var Util = {
  getStyle: function(style) {
    return parseInt(style.width) + ...
  },
  getOffsetWidth: ...
};
```

Comment: The 10 in parseInt isn't necessarily the default value. From MDN: "An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned string. Always specify this parameter to eliminate reader confusion and to guarantee predictable behavior. Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified."

Comment: Sorry, but this answer completely misses the point. I refer you to .... oh well, never mind.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot: OP's question was why those variables are retained. I understand the value in using closures to define private methods, but it's not a pattern that should be blindly applied to every situation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's a module written in the Module Pattern.

The self-exeuting anonymous function forms a closure - or a set of closures if you are so minded (I'm not) - establishing four privileged methods exposed via the return expression as properties of `Util`.

This pattern may also include private vars/methods, which are established in exactly the same scope as `getStyle`, `getOffsetWidth` etc, but are not exposed via the return expression.

This is a perfectly valid way to establish one or more singleton "namespace" objects, which is precisely the objective of the Module Pattern.