# Different between (function(){})() and (function(){}()) , self invoking anonymous function

Tags: javascript, self-invoking-function

Look at the placement of the parenthesis, is that any different?

( func )( )

```
(function(){

})();
```

and ( func( ) )

```
(function(){

}());
```

Comment: It does the same thing, but the second one is more semantically correct IMO.

Comment: Same thing only one is wrapped in parenthesis which don't do anything...

Comment: get your dog balls in!

Comment: Also: [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions) and [Is there a difference between (function() {…}()); and (function() {…})();?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3783007/218196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically the first defines an anonymous function, then calls it, the second defines an anonymous function which calls itself as it's defined.  Realistically, they are identical.

Comment: What's the difference between "then calls it" and "calls itself"? How can something "call itself"?

Comment: It's to do with returns and calls.  The first set of code, creates a function which is returned to the caller, then the caller executes it. The second returns the result of the executed function (i.e. the function has self executed).  In a much more complicated scenario I guess this could have different results, but I can't actually think of such a scenario.

Comment: No, the function is not "returned" to anybody. The function expression is *evaluated* to a function, as a part of a call expression - in both cases. There is *no* scenario in which they have a different result, except when the syntactic elements are parts of expressions that mean something completely different (when the grouping brackets are no grouping operator).