# IIFE injected code causes massive memoryleak?

Tags: javascript, browser, code-injection, iife

I'm writing a simple chrome extension and I've encountered very weird issue. I have a code that I inject like this

```
element.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('inject.js');
document.head.appendChild(element);
```

**Injects.js** itself:

```
(function() {
   //my code here
}());
```

The code itself is nothing special, I use code similar to [monkeyPatch](https://github.com/rauenzi/BetterDiscordApp/blob/master/js/main.js#L1236) to patch some original page functions and receive event data from them and my code on its own only has one anonymous function `setTimeout{}`, the rest is just data/DOM manipulation.

Now, the weird thing is if I change the function I wrap my code into to [IIFE example:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```
(function () {
    //my code
})();
```

I start to get insane memoryleak, like, few Gb in 5-7 minutes.

*I'm not very verse in JS and its ecosystem  - what could cause that?* I'd like to understand it and avoid similar issues it in future. Let me know if more context needed.

---

**EDIT:** 
*1. someone linked:*
[Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)
Interesting how it mentions: `Does the former take up memory by leaving around a global, anonymous function?`

*2. also this is interesting:* https://stackoverflow.com/a/3783287/8313379

None of these answer my question which is valid - 2Gb leaked memory in 10 minutes still here.

Comment: Those are both IIFEs. [The location of the parenthesis does not matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions) (if this is the only code). There seems to be something else at play.

Comment: That's the thing - I can only change the function wrapper syntax right now and the issue is back. It makes ZERO sense and that's why it is weird.

Comment: Try to make a minimal reproducible example of the injected code, and file a bug report against Chrome. I guess you'll find better help there than here on SO.

Comment: Well, you talk about intercepting events and whatnot, and leaving event handlers uncollected is a cause of memory leaks... But the code you've shown shows, well not much to cause any memory usage, let alone a leak.

Comment: You need to show `//my code here`