# Is there any difference between putting function call on a self-executing javascript function before or after final parenthesis

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)

The answer might be a simple no but I'm just curious.

I've seen self executing functions written as

```
(function() {
//...
}());
```

and

```
(function() {
//...
})();
```

where the parenthesis containing the function is closed *before* it is called.  Both seem to have exactly the same effect so I just wondered if there might be any difference in performance?

Comment: yep looks like it - I googled but obviously not well enough

Comment: You should close this since pimvdb's comment addresses it.