# Meaning of statement in JS

Tags: javascript

Trying to figure out what this means in javascript.

```
(function(document) { ... } )(document);
```

It is isn't using jQuery, so is this just a javascript way of making this wait till document is ready to execute?
Thanks.

Comment: A general pattern is to use immediately invoked function expressions `(function () { /* code here */ }());` to create nested scopes (variable environments). So, if you have a block of code within a whole lot of other code, and that block needs a bunch of variables, it makes sense to use that pattern to prevent those variables from polluting the outer code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't wait for the document to be ready, this will execute the content of the function immediately. Putting the function definition in parenthesis makes it an expression, which returns a value being the function, making it directly executable. This pattern is called an [Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE)](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/).

This is probably used in conjunction with a minifier like the [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

Inside the function, `document` is a local variable. This makes it possible for the minifier to reduce its name to a one or two character name.

Note also that all variables defined inside the function will be local : they won't leak in the global scope, which may be interesting if this is only part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

This creates an anonymous function that takes a single argument, and immediately calls it passing `document` as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
function(document) { ... }
```

creates a function taking one paremeter.

This:

```
(function(document) { ... })
```

makes it (the code, not the function) a valid expression. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions).

This:

```
(function(document) { ... } )(document);
```

calls that function with document as a parameter.

It's a basic modularization pattern. In different environments you could've passed some other object instead of document, but nothing inside that function has to know bout it.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **self-executed function**. It evaluates the anonymous function taking a parameter called `document` with that parameter passed in.