# any different between (function( ) { } ( ) ) and (function() { } ) ( )

Tags: javascript, syntax

Example:

```
 var hello = (function(text) { 
     return "hello " + text
  }("world"))
```

And

```
var hello = (function(text) { 
    return "hello " + text
})("world")
```

are they the same?

Comment: please check again, it's not duplicate.

Comment: Just check the duplicate of the duplicate of the duplicate of the duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions

Comment: my bad, yes I should've closed as a dupe of the dupe of the dupe. @elclanrs feel free to reopen and close again.

Comment: ops, thanks! a long journey haha.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté , it's OK, because finally it's duplicate of many duplicate as elclanrs said lol, thanks for everything.