# Javascript Module pattern and closures

Tags: closures, javascript

I'm trying to get my head around the module pattern in Javascript and have come across various different ways that I can see to do it.  What is the difference (if any) between  the following:

```
Person = function() {
    return {
        //...
    }
};
person1 = Person();

function Person2() {
    return {
        //...
    }
}
person2 = Person2();


person3 = function() {
    return {
        //...
    }
}();

person4 = (function() {
    return {
        // ...
    }
})();

person5 = (function() {
    return {
        // ...
    }
}());
```

They all seem to do the same thing to me.

Comment: Aside from the fact that you're not declaring your variables with `var` and for some you will have a leftover function, they all do the same thing in this particular example. Other (more complicated) examples may have different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// This creates a function, which then returns an object.
// Person1 isn't available until the assignment block runs.
Person = function() {
    return {
        //...
    }
};
person1 = Person();


// Same thing, different way of phrasing it.
// There are sometimes advantages of the
// two methods, but in this context they are the same.
// Person2 is available at compile time.
function Person2() {
    return {
        //...
    }
}

person2 = Person2();


// This is identical to 'person4'
// In *this* context, the parens aren't needed
// but serve as a tool for whoever reads the code.
// (In other contexts you do need them.)
person3 = function() {
    return {
        //...
    }
}();


// This is a short cut to create a function and then execute it,
// removing the need for a temporary variable.
// This is called the IIFE (Immediate Invoked Function Expression)
person4 = (function() {
    return {
        // ...
    }
})();


// Exactly the same as Person3 and Person4 -- Explained below.
person5 = (function() {
    return {
        // ...
    }
}());
```

In the contexts above,

- = function() {}();
- = (function() {}());
- = (function() {})();

All do exactly the same thing.

I'll break them down.

```
function() {}();
<functionExpression>(); // Call a function expression.

(<functionExpression>()); // Wrapping it up in extra parens means nothing.
// Nothing more than saying (((1))) + (((2)))


(<functionExpression>)(); 
// We already know the extra parens means nothing, so remove them and you get
<functionExpression>();  // Which is the same as case1
```

Now, all of that said == why do you sometimes need parens?

Because this is a *function statement)

```
function test() {};
```

In order to make a function expression, you need some kind of operator before it.

```
(function test() {})
!function test() {}
+function test() {}
```

all work.

By standardizing on the parens, we are able to:

- Return a value out of the IIFE
- Use a consistent way to let the reader of the code know it is an IIFE, not a regular function.

Answer (score 0):

The first two aren't a module pattern, but a factory function - there is a `Person` "constructor" that can be invoked multiple times. For the semantic difference see [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/q/336859/1048572).

The other three are [IIFEs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572), which all do exactly the same thing. For the syntax differences, see [Explain the encapsulated anonymous function syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1634268/1048572) and [Location of parenthesis for auto-executing anonymous JavaScript functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3384504/1048572).

Comment: I'd really like to close this as a duplicate, but it's too many different questions asked in a single post.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a extremely detail page explaining this kind of stuff

Sth called [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Hope will help.