# What is difference between (function(){}()) and (function(){})()?

Tags: javascript, closures, anonymous-function

Could someone please tell me the difference between:

```
(function(){}())
```

and

```
(function(){})()
```

I dont see any difference when I run this code.

Comment: No difference, two syntaxes for the exact same outcome - declaring an anonymous function and executing it immediately (immediately invoked function expression - IIFE)

Comment: This is a duplicate. I'll go find the original.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions

Comment: according to Douglas Crockford, the second version looks like dogs balls hanging off the end - so, there's that