# (function(){}) vs function(){}();

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, anonymous-function, iife

Consider the following two examples:

First:

```
var x = (function(){  return 786;  }());
```

Second:

```
var y = function(){  return 786;  }();
```

I know that we can't use `function(){  return 786;  }();` directly as an anoomymus self calling function but now since I am assigining it to variable `x` I can use this function. So,

- Is there any difference in result of the behaviour of variable `x` in *First* and *Second* method?

Comment: None, there's no difference. It's the same as `var x = (786);` and `var x = 786;`. Grouping the values between parenthesys will return the **last** value. Example: `var x = (5, function(){  return 786;  }());` will set `x = 786`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel But then why does javascript allow `(function(){  return 786;  }());` but not `function(){  return 786;  }();`?

Comment: It does... If you run it, both do exactly the same. This is exactly the same as `var x = [786][0];` and `var x = {x: 786}.x;`, in terms of final result and (in some way) syntax. Same as `var x = {x: function(){ return 786; }}.x();`  or `var x = {x: function(){ return 786; }()}.x;`.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Do you mean to say we can use `function(){ return 786; }()` wherever an expression is expected for example `(//some expression)`

Comment: Yes. That's, in a very resumed form and (possibly slightly) innacurate way. I haven't found an example where it can't be used. But, doesn't mean there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

No. There wouldn't be any difference.

Wrapping the function in parentheses converts them from a `function declaration` to an `expression` and it is ok for a valid `expression` to be run on its own.

```
var x = (function(){  return 786;  }());
```

Here, the anonymous function wrapped in parentheses is an expression which executes the function and return `786`, assigning it to the `var x`. Since the anonymous function is a valid expression, it can be run separately also.

```
var y = function(){  return 786;  }();
```

Here, the complete statement is an assignment `expression` and thus, it is executed and stores the value `786` to `var y`.

For further reading, check out the following links:

[/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions)

http://kangax.github.io/nfe/#function-statements