# IIFE Syntax best practice

Tags: javascript, iife

This is from MDN web docs

```
(function () {
    //statements
})();
```

But i've seen this usage down below too

```
(function() {
    //statements
}());
```

It seems both works. But which is best practice and why is there such difference? First one seems more appropriate imo

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384504/location-of-parenthesis-for-auto-executing-anonymous-javascript-functions) likely dupe.

Comment: or `;(async () => {})()`.. scope or sometimes prefrence

Comment: @ggorlen hmm, yeah likely. Well, i think i got it. Thanks

Comment: Glad it worked. I already burned my dupe vote on something silly otherwise I'd vote to close.