# Passing parameters in Javascript onClick event

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to pass a parameter in the onclick event. Below is a sample code:

```
<div id="div"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var div = document.getElementById('div');

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       var link = document.createElement('a');
       link.setAttribute('href', '#');
       link.innerHTML = i + '';
       link.onclick=  function() { onClickLink(i+'');};
       div.appendChild(link);
       div.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
       }

   function onClickLink(text) {
       alert('Link ' + text + ' clicked');
       return false;
       }
    </script>
```

However whenever I click on any of the links the alert always shows 'Link 10 clicked'!

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This happens because the i propagates up the scope once the function is invoked. You can avoid this issue using a closure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   var link = document.createElement('a');
   link.setAttribute('href', '#');
   link.innerHTML = i + '';
   link.onclick = (function() {
      var currentI = i;
      return function() { 
          onClickLink(currentI + '');
      }
   })();
   div.appendChild(link);
   div.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
}
```

Or if you want more concise syntax, I suggest you use Nick Craver's solution.

Comment: Awesome description of this Jamie!

Comment: Ha! Because that *closure* which we define on the RHS of `link.onclick = ` has access to the function containing it, which means the `i` inside there is a reference to the outer `i`, and not a copied value (as with normal *pass by value* passing of arguments)! :)) Lovely. I finally understand this :D

Answer (score 39):

This is happening because they're all referencing the *same* `i` variable, which is changing every loop, and left as `10` at the end of the loop.  You can resolve it using a closure like this:

```
link.onclick = function(j) { return function() { onClickLink(j+''); }; }(i);
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VtxA8/1/)

Or, make `this` be the link you clicked in that handler, like this:

```
link.onclick = function(j) { return function() { onClickLink.call(this, j); }; }(i);
```

[You can try that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VtxA8/2/)

Comment: Just to be clear: are you returning the declaration of an anonymous function which accepts a parameter _j_ and at the same moment you are passing the actual parameter too? (the _(i)_)

Comment: @dierre - The `(i)` invokes the `function(j)` with the parameter being the current `i`, triggering it to return the function in which a copied value is in the closure, no longer connected to `i`, make sense?

Comment: It seems the same thing I'm saying but I'm not sure:
to me _function(j) { return function() { onClickLink(j+''); }; }_ is _MyAnonymFunction(j)_.
What I'm seeing is _link.onclick = MyAnonymFunction(i);_

Comment: @dierre - Use the back tick (tilde key) for comment code :) I'm not sure how to describe it differently, you're invoking the anonymous function that returns another anonymous function, but with a different variable since it came from a different closure (the outer function).

Comment: I've just discovered the Ctrl-K shortcut but does not work on comments. BTW I got it. I'm sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 3):

```
link.onclick = function() { onClickLink(i+''); };
```

Is a closure and stores a reference to the variable `i`, not the value that `i` holds when the function is created. One solution would be to wrap the contents of the `for` loop in a function do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) (function(i) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    link.innerHTML = i + '';
    link.onclick=  function() { onClickLink(i+'');};
    div.appendChild(link);
    div.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
}(i));
```

Comment: I think you've got some brackets misbalanced there. Should it be `})(i);` on the last line?

Comment: That works, as does omitting the outer parentheses, but this is the "Crockford-approved" style: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939386/javascript-immediate-function-invocation-syntax

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div id="div"></div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   var div = document.getElementById('div');

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       var f = function() {
           var link = document.createElement('a');
           var j = i; // this j is scoped to our anonymous function
                      // while i is scoped outside the anonymous function,
                      //  getting incremented by the for loop
           link.setAttribute('href', '#');
           link.innerHTML = j + '';
           link.onclick=  function() { onClickLink(j+'');};
           div.appendChild(link);
           div.appendChild(document.createElement('br')); // lower case BR, please!
       }(); // call the function immediately
   }

   function onClickLink(text) {
       alert('Link ' + text + ' clicked');
       return false;
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

or you could use this line:

```
 link.setAttribute('onClick', 'onClickLink('+i+')');
```

instead of this one:

```
link.onclick=  function() { onClickLink(i+'');};
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simple way ( might not be the best practice) but works like charm. Build the HTML tag of your element(hyperLink or Button) dynamically with javascript, and can pass multiple parameters as well.

```
// variable to hold the HTML Tags 
var ProductButtonsHTML  ="";

//Run your loop
for (var i = 0; i < ProductsJson.length; i++){
// Build the <input> Tag with the required parameters for Onclick call. Use double quotes.

ProductButtonsHTML += " <input type='button' value='" + ProductsJson[i].DisplayName + "'  
onclick = \"BuildCartById('" + ProductsJson[i].SKU+ "'," + ProductsJson[i].Id + ")\"></input> ";

}

// Add the Tags to the Div's innerHTML.
document.getElementById("divProductsMenuStrip").innerHTML = ProductButtonsHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably better to create a dedicated function to create the link so you can avoid creating two anonymous functions. Thus:

```
<div id="div"></div>

<script>
  function getLink(id)
  {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    link.innerHTML = id;
    link.onclick = function()
    {
      onClickLink(id);
    };
    link.style.display = 'block';
    return link;
  }
  var div = document.getElementById('div');
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
  {
    div.appendChild(getLink(i.toString()));
  }
</script>
```

Although in both cases you end up with two functions, I just think it is better to wrap it in a function that is semantically easier to comprehend.

Answer (score 1):

onclick vs addEventListener. A matter of preference perhaps (where IE>9).

```
// Using closures
function onClickLink(e, index) {   
    alert(index);
    return false;
}

var div = document.getElementById('div');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    link.innerHTML = i + '';
    link.addEventListener('click', (function(e) {
        var index = i;
        return function(e) {
            return onClickLink(e, index);
        }
    })(), false);
    div.appendChild(link);
    div.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
}
```

How abut just using a plain data-* attribute, not as cool as a closure, but..

```
function onClickLink(e) {       
    alert(e.target.getAttribute('data-index'));
    return false;
}

var div = document.getElementById('div');

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.setAttribute('href', '#');
    link.setAttribute('data-index', i);
    link.innerHTML = i + ' Hello';        
    link.addEventListener('click', onClickLink, false);
    div.appendChild(link);
    div.appendChild(document.createElement('BR'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work from JS without coupling to HTML:

```
document.getElementById("click-button").onclick = onClickFunction;

function onClickFunction()
{
    return functionWithArguments('You clicked the button!');
}

function functionWithArguments(text) {
    document.getElementById("some-div").innerText = text;
}
```