# Is it possible to set/pass parameters for a traditional onclick event handler?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, onclick

For example, how would one pass data through the argument `myvar` with the following code:

```
<script>
function test(myvar) {
  alert('Testing: ' + myvar);
}
</script>

<div id="testDiv"> ... Text ... </div>


<script>
document.getElementById("testDiv").onclick = test;
</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495679/passing-parameters-in-javascript-onclick-event

Comment: @DevlshOne without jQuery, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
document.getElementById("testDiv").onclick = function() {
   test("hello there");
};
```

Comment: The parameter needs to be varying, not hard-coded. So, for example, if you have a table of rows, each row index could be passed in the `myvar` parameter.

Comment: @reformed: You can do whatever you want within the event handler. For example getting the row index it pass it to `test`.