# Javascript: variable.onclick instead of window.onclick?

Tags: variables, onclick

Hi I'm trying to get a variable to increment by one when I click on any one of my divs.

this code works for if I click on the page or window in general:

```
var click = 0;
window.onclick = function () {
click++;

console.log(click);
}
```

but it has to only work for when I click on one of the 36 buttons inside a container.

I tried replacing "window" with my function that is connected to my div "buttons" but that didn't work.

an example of what I'm trying to do is:

```
var click = 0;
myFunction.onclick = function () {
click++;

console.log(click);
}
```

Here is my function:

```
var imgArray = [], []; 
function onClickCard(image)
{
image.src=imgArray[parseInt(image.name.substring(0, 1)) - 1]           [parseInt(image.name.substring(1, 2)) - 1];
}
```

Comment: you need to put the call to onclick inside of the div as one of its attributes.  <div onclick="myfunction()"> </div>

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495679/passing-parameters-in-javascript-onclick-event

Comment: @harmonickey, don't suggest inline script please. Better with a click handler.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use jquery [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function on element.
2. If you do not want to use jquery, try this:

   document.onclick = function(event) {
       var target= event.target;
       if (target.nodeName == "BUTTON") {
           alert("button clicked");
       }
   };
3. Directly add on click inside the element definition as suggested above in comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plain Javascript, use this:

```
var click = 0;
window.onload = function () {
    var buttons = document.getElementById('container').querySelectorAll('div.button');
    console.log(buttons);
    for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].onclick = function () {
            click++;
            document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = click;
        }
    }
}
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VDcUv/)

In this demo I assumed you container has a ID `#container`, and your buttons are `div` elements with class `.button`.