# Pass parameters to onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I send parameters in `onclick` function using Javascript.
The following are the variables, need to set in `onclick` function.

```
var address ="Madison Avenue New York NY 10022";
var title ="Sydney NSW";

$('#MapDiv').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showGoogleMap();"><img src="assets/CommonAssets/time.png" /></a>');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing parameters in Javascript onClick event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495679/passing-parameters-in-javascript-onclick-event)

Comment: Thans carth..Its working fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var address = "Madison Avenue New York NY 10022";
var title = "Sydney NSW";
$('#MapDiv').html('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showGoogleMap(\''+address+'\',\''+title+'\');"><img src="assets/CommonAssets/time.png" /></a>');
```

Answer (score 1):

Setup an `ID` for `<a>` and then in jQuery, use:

```
$('#id').click(function(address, title){
 //code here
})
```

Comment: This will fail because the `a` tag is created dynamically.  So try to do with `on` event handler attachment.

Comment: Good catch. :) Deleting this answer in 5 mins.

Comment: Why're you deleting the answer, instead update it.  `$(document).on('click', '#id', function(address, title){
 //code here
})`

Comment: oh wait, I got it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/kqMr9/ (I had a stupid typo).

Comment: Thats my bad actually I didn't noticed that you have loaded the click event after generating the `a` tag whereas check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kqMr9/3/ you will understand what I tried to convey.