# Is there a difference between (function(){})(); and (function(){}());

Tags: javascript, function, parentheses

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript: immediate function invocation syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939386/javascript-immediate-function-invocation-syntax)

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/difference-between-function-and-function)

there, the author asked about the difference between

**`(`**`function(){}`**`)`**`();`

and

`function(){}();`

the purpose of the first is, among other things, to inform the reader that the function is to be immediately executed. I have also seen this version

**`(`**`function(){}()`**`)`**;

Is this the same as the above two?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939386/javascript-immediate-function-invocation-syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This variant `function(){}();` will give you syntax error

Comment: In this form yes, but this is not an answer to the question.