# javascript self-executing functions - different syntax

Tags: javascript, syntax

I've seen 2 versions of self executing javascript functions:

```
(function() { ... })()
```

and

```
(function() { ... }())
```

note the different placement of the function execution "()"

Is there a difference between these two?

Comment: The word closure here can cause confusion

Comment: see my last paragraph here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259694/whats-the-technique-that-the-google-analytics-tracking-code-uses/12259808#12259808

Comment: This question acually is a duplicate as Rob W suggested. Sorry about that - didn't find it while searching.

Answer (score 5):

There are many ways to get the effect of what you're doing, and strictly speaking this topic has only tangential relation to the subject of closures.

The problem is this: in JavaScript, the `function` keyword serves **two different purposes**:

1. It introduces a **function declaration statement**, which is kind-of like a `var` statement (variable declaration) but for a function;
2. It introduces a **function literal** expression in the context of a larger expression.

Now the problem is that when the parser sees `function` at the beginning of a statement, it assumes you mean to declare a function; that is, case 1 above.  When you declare a function, you cannot call it in the same statement; the function declaration statement **just** declares the function.

Thus, if what you want is a statement that consists **only** of the creation of a function and its immediate invocation, you have to put the parser in the mood to parse an expression. Putting the whole thing in parentheses is just one way of doing that.

Any "trick" that convinces the parser that what it's seeing is an expression statement will do:

```
var dummy = function() { ... whatever ... } ();

!function() { ... whatever ... } ();

0 + function() { ... whatever ... } ();
```

All of those, and countless other examples, set things up such that when the parser sees the `function` keyword, it does so in the middle of an expression.

If Mr. Eich had picked a different keyword for the instantiation of a function object mid-expression (like *lambda* for example), there'd be no problem, because you could then just say

```
lambda () { ... whatever ... } ();
```

He didn't, however.

Answer (score 1):

The parenthesis ensure you have an expression (which cannot starts by the `function` keyword), so that it may be executed.

From [ECMAscript Language Specification](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-12.4) :

> Also, an
>   ExpressionStatement cannot start with the function keyword because
>   that might make it ambiguous with a FunctionDeclaration.

This works too :

```
(((((function() {...}))())));​
```

Comment: Well not so much "useless"; they do serve a purpose but they don't have any effect on the *value* of the expression.

Answer (score 1):

The correct term for either of these is an immediately executing function.

Although both of these work in the same way, [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/code.html) recommends the latter for reasons of readability.

> When a function is to be invoked immediately, the entire invocation
>   expression should be wrapped in parens so that it is clear that the
>   value being produced is the result of the function and not the
>   function itself.

So if you want to follow that advice, you should prefer to use:

```
(function() { ... }())
```

Answer (score 0):

Former is better because it treats Function as a `first-class citizen'. It use parenthesis to wrap the function and invoke it.

Em..as to latter, it also avoid syntax ambiguous.

But I recommend the former.