# What does the ! part of !function(){...}(); mean?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the exclamation mark do before the function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3755606/what-does-the-exclamation-mark-do-before-the-function)

So I've come across the use of the following by the twitter share button code:

```
!function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
```

And I was just wondering what the `!function` bit does.

I'm guessing is short for `(function(){...})();` but I couldn't find anything online to confirm it.

Comment: @Quentin ah thanks, I had a search but of course searching for "!function" doesn't help do much :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While @elias-van-ootegem got it mostly right, many browsers will consider it a syntax error without the bang.

```
function() { ... }() // Bad
!function() { ... }() // Good
(function() { ... })() // Better, more readable.
(function() { ... }()) // Best
```

Comment: `(function() { ... }())` even better :)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/12259808/1098851 last paragraph

Comment: @NatIsGleek thanks very much! Useful to see all the ways and their ranking.

Comment: @NatIsGleek: Which browsers consider it a SyntaxError with the `!`? Please name at least one.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to say without @user1689607