# closure syntax: (function a(){})() == (function a(){}())?

Tags: javascript, closures

I've noticed that [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/) seems to use both interchangeably.

1.

```
(function a() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    //
    a();
  });
})();
```

2.

```
(function a() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    //
    a();
  });
}());
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? x:

Comment: @Kay: Thanks, I voted to close. I searched but didn't find.

Comment: No problem. Searching for punctuation marks is quite difficult.

Comment: @Kay I was looking for that too. May I ask how you found it?

Comment: I googled "stackoverflow javascript parentheses function".

Comment: Thanks, I tried similar searches but couldn't find it... @Kay

Comment: Here is another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/939386/immediate-function-invocation-syntax

Answer (score 1):

There is no one "closure syntax" : any syntax ensuring you build a function expression, that is a function expression that the compiler can't confuse with the start of a function definition, and you call it is OK. Here, both work.

You could for example have used

```
+function(){
  ...
}();
```

Simply choose the one that is the most readable and the less surprising. I think the first one, in which the call parenthesis are the most visible, is the most used and expected.