# getElementsByClassName not finding uls

Tags: javascript, html, html-lists, getelementsbyclassname

I am unable to get my code working correctly in Chrome however when I paste my code into JSFIDDLE it works correctly. I am trying to get all ul tags in the document using getElementsByClassName and then all lis within the one of the uls. When I use getElementsByClassName("ul") it is finding none in Chrome, however if I remove either one of the two divs before the uls getElementsByClassName("ul") finds all of them so the divs seem to be what is breaking the JS.

I was unable to reproduce the problem in JSFIDDLE as the code worked correctly there but here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/zTP9H/

```
var sElements = document.getElementsByClassName("HeaderWrapWide");
var catOne = document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
alert("number of ul: " + catOne.length);

var liTags = catOne[3].getElementsByTagName("li");
alert("number of li: " + liTags.length);
```

Thanks

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you sure you are running this javascript AFTER the html is added to the page? jsfiddle probably renders html/scripts in a different way to your webpage and hence that is why it works there. If your javascript is in the head part of your HTML you could well have this behaviour - try using jquery on document ready function http://api.jquery.com/ready/ or move your JS to the bottom of the page

I cant see anything wrong with your code

Comment: Thanks, moving main.js to the bottom fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have the above JS code within your **`head`** tag.  So wrap it with [Immediate function invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/939386/1671639)

```
(function () {
   //ToDos
})();
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/zTP9H/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute the code in the `<head></head>`
like you have it, then try wrapping your code in a
function like this if you don't want to use jQuery.
Also, this doesn't work in IE so check [caniuse.com/#search=DOMContentLoaded](http://caniuse.com/#search=DOMContentLoaded)

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    your code here.
  })
```