# When should I use the syntax "(function() {...})();"?

Tags: javascript

My query is used in cases that "(function() {...})();" Given that I am not a plugin. 
For example "http://piecesofrakesh.blogspot.com/2009/03/downloading-javascript-files-in.html"

```
(function() {        
  var s = [
    "/javascripts/script1.js",
    "/javascripts/script2.js"
  ];

  var sc = "script", tp = "text/javascript", sa = "setAttribute", doc = document, ua = window.navigator.userAgent;

  for(var i=0, l=s.length; i<l; ++i) {
    if(ua.indexOf("MSIE")!==-1 || ua.indexOf("WebKit")!==-1) {
      doc.writeln("<" + sc + " type=\"" + tp + "\" src=\"" + s[i] + 
          "\" defer></" + sc + ">");
    } else {
      var t=doc.createElement(sc);
      t[sa]("src", s[i]);
      t[sa]("type", tp);
      doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(t);
    }
  }
})();
```

Or

```
var s = [
    "/javascripts/script1.js",
    "/javascripts/script2.js"
];
...
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's exactly the question?

Comment: "Given that I am not a plugin" is cute :-)

Comment: Sorry, I write very bad in English. The script is not a plugin, in which case it is useful to use this structure "(function (){...}();"

Comment: Agreed, I hope when I have to use a language other than English, people have patience for me....

Comment: i *think* this is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/difference-between-function-and-function - Difference between (function(){})(); and function(){}();

Comment: @andres descalzo: I didn't mean that offensively; really no need to be sorry. Just thought it was a cute expression.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is done to avoid naming conflicts.

When you declare a function, that function has its own namespace for variables. By wrapping the code in a function that is immediately invoked, you avoid overwriting global variables with your own values.

In this case `s` and `sc` are assigned a value. If you did that at the global scope and other scripts were already using variables with those names for a different purpose, that would cause those other scripts to fail. By introducing the new scope, the identifiers `s` and `sc` now refer to different (locally-bound) variables than the variables named `s` and `sc` that exist at the global scope.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe these questions will help you out:

- [Difference between (function(){})(); and function(){}();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/difference-between-function-and-function)
- [What do parentheses surrounding a JavaScript object||function||class declaration mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440739/what-do-parentheses-surrounding-a-javascript-objectfunctionclass-declaration)
- [Javascript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)

Answer (score 3):

`(function() {...})();` is a self-invoking anonymous function i.e. a function with no name that is executed straight away. Since JavaScript has function scope, using self-invoking anonymous functions limits the scope of variables inside the function to the function itself, thereby avoiding any conflicts that might occur otherwise.

In jQuery, a self-invoking anonymous function is used quite often by plugin authers to reference the jQuery object with the `$` symbol inside of the function. For example

```
(function($) {

    /* plugin code here */

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2):

Idiom `(function() {...})();` limits scope of your variables. So in first case `s` (and `sc`, `tp` etc) won't be accessible anywhere outside function body. In second case you will be able to access it. So `(function() {...})();` keeps you from namespace pollution. Whether you need that is another question. You may like to google something like "scope javascript". There's a nice [article](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/).