# How to call a public function in a Javascript namesapce

Tags: javascript

When I create a JS namespace (myNamespace) with a public method (myPublicMethod)

jsfile1.js

```
var myNamespace=(function() {

  var myPublicMethod=function(){
    alert("hello world");
  }

  return
  {
     myPublicMethod:myPublicMethod
  };

})();
```

and then have a separate .js file which encapsulates its methods

jsfile2.js

```
(function(){
  myNamespace.myPublicMethod();
})();
```

The two files are then included in an html file

```
<script src="jsfile1.js"...>
<script src="jsfile2.js" ...>
```

When I try to call myPublicMethod() I get an error that myNamespace does not exist. Is this because it is encapsulated in the jsfile2.js file?

Thanks

Comment: You missed the most crucial change... I've revised jimr's answer to point it out explicitly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason that the function isn't defined in your namespace is because of the lines

```
return
{
   myPublicMethod:myPublicMethod
}
```

An implied semicolon is inserted after the return, so what the interpreter sees is actually something like:

```
return;
{
   myPublicMethod:myPublicMethod
}
```

So nothing is actually returned from the function, and the value of `myNamespace` remains `undefined`. The fix is easy: just put the opening brace on the same line as the `return`:

```
return { 
  myPublicMethod: myPublicMethod
};
```

(note that the trailing semicolon is *not **strictly** required*, but a good idea anyway if you ever plan to use something like a [minifier](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html))

Also, the way you're defining the function in the first file [is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/difference-between-function-and-function).  It should be

```
var myNamespace = (function() {
...
})();
```

Comment: Revised according to your example, changes above, and still getting same error.

Comment: Moving the { to the same line as the return worked.

Interesting that you have to put the opening brace on the same line as the "return". Seems inconsistent with the way some other aspects of the language work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Would changing file 1 to the following work?

```
var myNamespace={

  myPublicMethod: function(){
    alert("hello world");
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missing parenthesis on your `myNamespace` function declaration, also you should use semicolons in your return statement:

```
var myNamespace = function () {

  var myPublicMethod = function(){
    alert("hello world");
  }

  return {
     myPublicMethod : myPublicMethod
  };
}();

myNamespace.myPublicMethod();
```