# what does it do? (function(){...}());

Tags: javascript, facebook

I was reading [facebook javascript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) when I saw the following syntaxt that I don't understand:
    (function(){...}());
Does anyone know what does it do?

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'your app id', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript function vs. ( function() { ... } ());](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806150/javascript-function-vs-function)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

it's an anonymous function, that gets called immediately after its declaration. It's used to create local variables without clobbering up the global scope. the variable `e` will not be visible nor accessible outside the function block

Comment: And why.. dare I ask.. wouldn't we want `e` to be visible or accessible?  Is it sort of like - _if a tree falls in the woods_...?