# Two ways of immediate call to anonymous function (function(d){ }() ); and (function(x){ } )();

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are “(function ( ) { } ) ( )” and “(function ( ) { } ( ) )” functionally equal in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5938802/are-function-and-function-functionally-equal-i)

My question having these special characters, I couldn't find a good answer. (Does anyone know how to search with them?)

I've seen two patterns to immediately calling anonymous functions http://jsfiddle.net/ukqS8/1/

```
(function(d) {
    document.write(d*2);
})(3);
```

and

```
(function(x) {
    document.write(x*2);
}(3));
```

The difference being where (3) is placed: inside or outside the closing parenthesis.

I found a good explanation for the second case here:

[javascript function vs. ( function() { ... } ());](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806150/javascript-function-vs-function)

which I understood as `function(x) {...}` creates a function object, (3) becomes its argument, and the enclosing () tells the interpreter that what's inside is a statement.

In the first case, it appears to make `(function(d) {...})` a statement that somehow is also a function, and then apply (3) to this statement/function.

So, they both appear to execute the same way. Is there really a difference here? Scope (I doubt it)? Is either option preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect.

Those are both function expressions; the placement of the parentheses makes no difference here.

However, [there can be a subtle difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5938845/34397).

Comment: That's a lot simpler, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: How did you find that question? I can get rid of this one.

Comment: @HeitorChang: I had remembered answering it.

Answer (score 1):

They execute exactly the same. The difference is only in syntax.