# JavaScript - ( function () {} () )?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript function vs. ( function() { … } ());](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806150/javascript-function-vs-function)

I'm seeing this pattern in several of [TodoMVC](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/)'s JS [source](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/architecture-examples/backbone/js/models/todo.js%29):

```
(function() {
    // ...
    // ...
}());
```

What's the specific meaning of this pattern? Note that it is not the self-invoking function which is `(function() {})();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What's the specific meaning of this pattern? Note that it is not the self-invoking function which is `(function() {})();`

You're incorrect, it **is** an Immediately Invoked Function Expression (IIFE). The parenthesis are just in a different place, but they bind the exact same way.

People often do it in the way you've described to get it to validate [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

It's used for scoping, as JavaScript only has function and global scope (ignoring `let`).

Comment: Is there any advantage wrapping the parenthesis this way over the other way around?

Comment: @Kay One passes JSLint, one doesn't. If passing JSLint is important to you, then use the appropriate form.

Comment: You ain't gonna get a more correct answer than this. The mention of JSLint makes it bulletproof. Damn that Crockford... always rearing his head in my text editor.