# Enclosing js function between ()?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between (function(){})(); and function(){}();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/difference-between-function-and-function)

I have seen it a lot by google:

```
(function(){/*code*/})
```

Why they enclose their function inside the parethesis?
Which is the difference between:

```
function(){/*code*/}
```

?

## Edit

Ok the questions should have been this:

Why they enclose their code into this:

```
(function(){/*code*/})();
```

Instead to write the code directly into the js flow?
Are there any benefits, different behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what you see is a self executing function:

```
var x = (function(bar){
    return bar;
})('foo')

alert(x);
```

Comment: @yes123: If it works, you can do *anything* you want. But this is a [known pattern](http://2007-2010.lovemikeg.com/2008/08/17/a-week-in-javascript-patterns-self-invocation/), and you should get acquainted with that kind of code.

Comment: They are also called "iffees" in the JS world. IIFE immediately invoked functions

Answer (score 15):

I usually use immediate functions to control the variable scope so as not to pollute the global name space. It's a very useful pattern.

```
(function (window, $, undefined) {
// This pattern gives you the following benefits:
//   * all variables defined in here are private
//   * can safely minify global variables: window, jQuery & undefined
//   * ensures that window, $, undefined mean what you expect
//   * global variables are localized so lookups are faster
}(this, jQuery));
```

So even if someone does `window = ‘Bob’` or the shortcut `$` doesn’t equal `jQuery` but instead is the Prototype library, the code inside this immediate function will still work correctly. While you may think to yourself “I’d never set `undefined` to something else”, keep in mind you’re not the only one putting code into the page; you can’t afford to have a poorly written ad script from DoubleClick bringing down the site, especially when it is so easily prevented.

**JavaScript’s global scope is like a public toilet. You can’t always avoid it, but try to limit your contact with surfaces.**

Comment: As I said to him too: why they do that, can't just add the code directly?

Comment: LOL.  I'm so glad I upvoted this today.  Happy 4/1 from SO.

Answer (score 4):

It's usually done to force the parser to treat it as a function *expression* and not a *declaration*.

Comment: You should elaborate.  Ie, `function foo(){}` is in the global scope and can be called via `foo()`, whereas `(function bar(){})` is not in the global scope.  Calling `bar()` will cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because usually the code looks like this:

```
(function(){/*code*/})();
```

The reason for the extra parenthesis is that this is not legal syntax:

```
function(){/*code*/}();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's needed for immediate functions as @daniellmb said.  See [explanation of expression closure](http://perfectionkills.com/a-closer-look-at-expression-closures/) for more information.