# What is the difference between these three module pattern implementations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I've seen the following three code blocks as examples of the JavaScript module pattern.  What are the differences, and why would I choose one pattern over the other?

**Pattern 1**

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    var firstName = firstName;
    var lastName = lastName;

    this.fullName = function () {
        return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
    };

    this.changeFirstName = function (name) {
        firstName = name;
    };
};

var jordan = new Person('Jordan', 'Parmer');
```

**Pattern 2**

```
function person (firstName, lastName) { 
    return {
        fullName: function () {
            return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
        },

        changeFirstName: function (name) {
            firstName = name;
        }
    };
};

var jordan = person('Jordan', 'Parmer');
```

**Pattern 3**

```
var person_factory = (function () {
    var firstName = '';
    var lastName = '';

    var module = function() {
        return {
            set_firstName: function (name) {
                               firstName = name;
                           },
            set_lastName: function (name) {
                              lastName = name;
                          },
            fullName: function () {
                          return firstName + ' ' + lastName;
                      }

        };
    };

    return module;
})();

var jordan = person_factory();
```

From what I can tell, the JavaScript community *generally* seems to side with pattern 3 being the best.  How is it any different from the first two?  It seems to me all three patterns can be used to encapsulate variables and functions.

NOTE: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647019/what-are-the-differences-between-these-three-types-of-module-pattern) doesn't actually answer the question, and I don't consider it a duplicate.

Comment: You're not aware of the fact that these three pieces create three fundamentally different behaviors, are you?

Comment: There is no "best". If the JavaScript community has decided that pattern 3 is best, then the JavaScript community is wrong. They're 3  different approaches, and each of them have their uses.

Comment: @Bergi - That is the nature of the question.  What are the differences?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: Module Pattern vs Constructor/Prototype pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790909/javascript-module-pattern-vs-constructor-prototype-pattern)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't consider them *module patterns* but more object instantiation patterns. Personally I wouldn't recommend any of your examples. Mainly because I think reassigning function arguments for anything else but method overloading is not good. Lets circle back and look at the two ways you can create Objects in JavaScript:

**Protoypes and the `new` operator**

This is the most common way to create Objects in JavaScript. It closely relates to Pattern 1 but attaches the function to the object prototype instead of creating a new one every time:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
};

Person.prototype.fullName = function () {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
};

Person.prototype.changeFirstName = function (name) {
    this.firstName = name;
};

var jordan = new Person('Jordan', 'Parmer');

jordan.changeFirstName('John');
```

**Object.create and factory function**

ECMAScript 5 introduced [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) which allows a different way of instantiating Objects. Instead of using the `new` operator you use `Object.create(obj)` to set the Prototype.

```
var Person =  {
    fullName : function () {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },

    changeFirstName : function (name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    }
}

var jordan = Object.create(Person);
jordan.firstName = 'Jordan';
jordan.lastName = 'Parmer';

jordan.changeFirstName('John');
```

As you can see, you will have to assign your properties manually. This is why it makes sense to create a factory function that does the initial property assignment for you:

```
function createPerson(firstName, lastName) {
    var instance = Object.create(Person);
    instance.firstName = firstName;
    instance.lastName = lastName;
    return instance;
}

var jordan = createPerson('Jordan', 'Parmer');
```

As always with things like this I have to refer to [Understanding JavaScript OOP](https://github.com/SampaJS/Entendendo-Javascript-Orientado-a-Objetos/blob/master/endentendo-javascript-poo.md) which is one of the best articles on JavaScript object oriented programming.

I also want to point out my own little library called [UberProto](http://daffl.github.com/uberproto/) that I created after researching inheritance mechanisms in JavaScript. It provides the `Object.create` semantics as a more convenient wrapper:

```
var Person = Proto.extend({
    init : function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    },

    fullName : function () {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    },

    changeFirstName : function (name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    }
});

var jordan = Person.create('Jordan', 'Parmer');
```

In the end it is not really about what "the community" seems to favour but more about understanding what the language provides to achieve a certain task (in your case creating new obejcts). From there you can decide a lot better which way you prefer.

**Module patterns**

It seems as if there is some confusion with module patterns and object creation. Even if it looks similar, it has different responsibilities. Since JavaScript *only has function scope* modules are used to *encapsulate functionality* (and not accidentally create global variables or name clashes etc.). The most common way is to wrap your functionality in a self-executing function:

```
(function(window, undefined) {
})(this);
```

Since it is just a function you might as well return something (your API) in the end

```
var Person = (function(window, undefined) {
    var MyPerson = function(firstName, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    };

    MyPerson.prototype.fullName = function () {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    };

    MyPerson.prototype.changeFirstName = function (name) {
        this.firstName = name;
    };

    return MyPerson;
})(this);
```

That's pretty much modules in JS are. They introduce a wrapping function (which is equivalent to a new scope in JavaScript) and (optionally) return an object which is the modules API.

Comment: These two links refer to #3 as the module pattern.  What's the difference?  http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern and http://macwright.org/2012/06/04/the-module-pattern.html

Comment: I updated my answer. The difference doesn't matter. Basically it usually comes down to what I am describing in my edit.

Answer (score 4):

First, as @Daff already mentioned, these are not all module patterns. Let's look at the differences:

### Pattern 1 vs Pattern 2

You might omit the useless lines

```
var firstName = firstName;
var lastName = lastName;
```

from pattern 1. Function arguments are already local-scoped variables, as you can see in your pattern-2-code.

Obviously, the functions are very similar. Both create a closure over those two local variables, to which only the (exposed) `fullName` and the `changeFirstName` functions have access to. The difference is what happens on instantiation.

- In pattern 2, you just return an object (literal), which inherits from `Object.prototype`.
- In pattern 1, you use the [`new` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) with a function that is called a "constructor" (and also properly capitalized). This will create an object that inherits from `Person.prototype`, where you could place other methods or default properties which all instances will share.

There are other variations of [constructor patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript). They might favor [public] properties on the objects, and put all methods on the prototype - you can mix such. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13418980/1048572) for how emulating class-based inheritance works.

When to use what? The prototype pattern is usually preferred, especially if you might want to extend the functionality of all `Person` instances - maybe not even from the same module. Of course there are use cases of pattern 1, too, especially for singletons that don't need inheritance.

### Pattern 3

…is now actually the [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript), using a closure for creating static, private variables. What you export from the closure is actually irrelevant, it could be any fabric/constructor/object literal - still being a "module pattern".

Of course the closure in your pattern 2 could be considered to use a "module pattern", but it's purpose is creating an instance so I'd not use this term. Better examples would be the Revealing Prototype Pattern or anything that extends already existing object, using the Module Pattern's closure - focusing on code modularization.

In your case the module exports a constructor function that returns an object to access the static variables. Playing with it, you could do

```
var jordan = person_factory();
jordan.set_firstname("Jordan");
var pete = person_factory();
pete.set_firstname("Pete");
var guyFawkes = person_factory();
guyFawkes.set_lastname("Fawkes");

console.log(jordan.fullname()); // "Pete Fawkes"
```

Not sure if this was expected. If so, the extra constructor to get the accessor functions seems a bit useless to me.

Comment: +1 Ah, excellent answer.  That actually cleared up quite a bit of confusion I was developing.  Coming from a c-based language background, I've gotten myself muddled on prototyping.

Answer (score 2):

"Which is best?" isn't really a valid question, here.
They all do different things, come with different trade-offs, and offer different benefits.
The use of one or the other or all three (or none) comes down to how you choose to engineer your programs.

Pattern #1 is JS' traditional take on "classes".

It allows for `prototyping`, which should really *not* be confused with `inheritance` in C-like languages.
Prototyping is more like `public static` properties/methods in other languages.
Prototyped methods also have ***NO ACCESS TO INSTANCE VARIABLES*** (ie: variables which aren't attached to `this`).

```
var MyClass = function (args) { this.thing = args; };
MyClass.prototype.static_public_property = "that";
MyClass.prototype.static_public_method   = function () { console.log(this.thing); };

var myInstance = new MyClass("bob");
myInstance.static_public_method();
```

Pattern #2 creates a single instance of a single object, with no implicit inheritance.

```
var MyConstructor = function (args) {
    var private_property = 123,
        private_method = function () { return private_property; },

        public_interface = {
            public_method : function () { return private_method(); },
            public_property : 456
        };

    return public_interface;
};


var myInstance = MyConstructor(789);
```

No inheritance, and every instance gets a ***NEW COPY*** of each function/variable.
This is quite doable, if you're dealing with objects which aren't going to have hundreds of thousands of instances per page.

Pattern #3 is like Pattern #2, except that you're building a Constructor and can include the equivalent of `private static` methods (you ***must*** pass in arguments, 100% of the time, and you ***must*** collect return statements, if the function is intended to return a value, rather than directly-modifying an object or an array, as these props/methods have no access to the instance-level data/functionality, despite the fact that the instance-constructor has access to all of the "static" functionality).
The practical benefit here is a lower memory-footprint, as each instance has a *reference* to these functions, rather than their own *copy* of them.

```
var PrivateStaticConstructor = function (private_static_args) {
    var private_static_props = private_static_args,
        private_static_method = function (args) { return doStuff(args); },

        constructor_function = function (private_args) {
            var private_props = private_args,
                private_method = function (args) { return private_static_method(args); },
                public_prop = 123,
                public_method = function (args) { return private_method(args); },

                public_interface = {
                    public_prop   : public_prop,
                    public_method : public_method
                };

            return public_interface;
        };

    return constructor_function;
};


var InstanceConstructor = PrivateStaticConstructor(123),
    myInstance = InstanceConstructor(456);
```

These are all doing very different things.