# SyntaxError for function(){}()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byLk5/). For me, it's just a self-executing empty function:

```
function(){}()
```

Google Chrome 16.0.912.4 dev-m returns the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Why? This is especially strange because adding extraneous brackets will remove the error:

```
(function(){})()
```

Comment: it seems like the browser expects a name after `function` using this notation

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423228/difference-between-function-and-function

Comment: Firefox gives the same error. That's because `function(){}` is the actual function you want to execute. So you have to add brackets around it to indicate that you mean the whole function!

Comment: Also interesting is that `x=function () {} ()` does not throw an error.

Comment: @kojiro Maybe the browser interprets it as `(x=function () {}) ()`.

Comment: @kojiro: If you have an assignment, everything on right side is an expression.

Comment: @ComFreek: No it does not, it is the same as `x = (function(){})();`

Comment: @ComFreek Actually the assignment is enough of a clue to let the interpreter know that it's a function expression and not a function *declaration*. This is covered in the question linked above, and also more thoroughly in [What is the difference between a function expression vs declaration in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013385)

Comment: @FelixKling You're right! Interesting link ;) By the way even IE 6 can handle such declarations!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ExpressionStatement :
>
> [lookahead ∉ {{, function}] Expression ;

Because a `function () {}()` is not a statement as defined in ES5.1

And a valid program has to be a statement.

[Expression Statement](http://es5.github.com/#x12.4).

however the following

`!function () {}();`

is a valid statement, so is using `()` and so is `var ret = function () {}()`

Comment: Why is `function(){}()` not a statement. It is the statement "execute the empty function", isn't it?

Comment: @Randomblue: There are two ways to interpret this and the standard is to interpret it as function declaration, which requires a name.