# need some info on declaring the variable in the following style

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript scope and closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631187/javascript-scope-and-closure)
>   [JavaScript - self executing functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085355/javascript-self-executing-functions)

What is the difference between the following code:

```
var someVar = (function(){
   // some code
})();
```

And

```
var someVar = function(){
   // some code
};
```

Can you point me to tutorials on the usage and explanation of first code?

It is hard to find the answer on Google, so I thought I would ask it here.

Thank you.

Comment: The first one is self-invoking.

Comment: Test yourself : http://jsfiddle.net/sdsmV/. The second way defines the function and the first way fire the function and put the return value in `someVar`.

Answer (score 1):

**First case**

Will be created and executed anonymous function. Function result will be stored in `someVar`.

```js
var someVar = (function(){
    console.log('function executed');
    return 1;
})();
// function executed
console.log(someVar);
// 1
```

**Second case**

Will be created anonymous function and it's reference will be stored in `someVar`.

```js
var someVar = function(){
    console.log('function executed');
    return 1;
};

var result = someVar();
// function executed
console.log(result);
// 1
```